# Display expired cache file when database/source is unavailable

Tags: cakephp

I have a controller where view is being cached using CakePHP CacheHelper:

```
public $cacheAction = array(
    'index'  => 3600
);
```

When the cache expires, CakePHP will attempt to establish connection with the source (database or external feed). In case the source is unavailable, it will notify the user that the connection is not available. Instead, I would like following two things to happen:

1. Instead of displaying "no connection" error, I would like to display
   existing cache file (expired cache) until the database/source
   connection is restored. After the connection is restored, the new cache is generated.
2. Capture the missing connection in the background and email the
   webadmin.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware Cake allows you to create you own cache engine, so by that you can extend the one you are using and expand the read function by the functionality you've mentioned, this should solve your problem, the only thing that concerns me is that the book doesn't state if view caching helper uses same cache engines as the rest of the app, but by assumption i'm guessing it does, it would be the only logical solution.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html